# SQL Server : sorting and checking

Tags: sql-server, sorting, if-statement, case

I have a table named `Logs`:

```
 ->OCCUR_TIME --date and time
 ->NAME --name of a person
 ->KIND --the kind of log (eg. 40 means `something`)
 ->VALUE --the value of the kind of log (eg. 99)
```

I have to create a query:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM        LOGS
WHERE       NAME='dude'
ORDER BY    KIND, OCCUR_TIME, VALUE;
```

Now this displays the logs and sorted by kind, then occur time (if occur_time is exactly the same it will then sort by value).

Notes:

- VALUE of a KIND must always be +1
- If not report a problem.

What if for an example there was a problem with the log and after the VALUE 400 the next VALUE is 398?

Example:

```
   Occur_Time                | Name    | Kind | Value
   2012-06-26 15:14:25.407     dude      40     398
   2012-06-27 16:55:28.730     dude      40     399
   2012-06-30 02:43:26.763     dude      40     400
   2012-06-30 05:26:32.673     dude      40     398 <-- data prob. (possible rollback)
   2012-06-30 16:35:28.330     dude      40     399 <-- problem continuing
   2012-06-20 20:29:51.207     dude      41     100 <-- no prob. bcoz its another kind
   2012-06-23 05:50:59.130     guy       40     500 <-- no prob. bcoz its another name
```

I want a query that will find the problem, and where it started. Like this?

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: so, for the same user, for the same kind, the value should always be getting bigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012, you would do this using the lag() function.

I'll assume you are using an earlier version, but post 2005.  You can do this with nested windows functions.

```
select name, KIND, OCCUR_TIME, VALUE,
       (case when max(testval) over (partition by kind, name) <> min(testval) over (partition by kind)
              then 'FAIL'
              else 'OKAY'
        end) as status
from (SELECT *,
             row_number() over (partition by kind, name order by occur_time, value) as seqnum,
             (value - row_number() over (partition by kind, name order by occur_time, value)) as testval
      FROM LOGS
      WHERE NAME='dude'
     ) t
  ORDER BY name, KIND, OCCUR_TIME, VALUE
```

The idea is to use row_number() to generate a sequence of numbers.  The difference between the value and the sequence should be a constant.  The outer query looks at the min and max values of these.  If they are different, you have a problem.

Comment: Hello, I'm using 2008. I'm testing your query now. Thank you/

Comment: Thanks, I have decided to use this. Tweak it a little.

Comment: Hello, one more thing. How to code to also make the NAME different?

Comment: Right now if I use this to run through all the logs, even though it is a different name, the seqnum continues.

Comment: Makes everything fail, unless i use WHERE NAME='dude'

Comment: My apologies.  I saw the requirement for the ordering by kind, but not by kind and name.  I fixed the query, including name in the partitions (and select clause).  If I made no syntax errors, this should fix that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not an ideal query, but this will list the problems:

```
select l1.*, l2.* 
from logs l1 -- self join on the columns that are the same
  inner join logs l2 on l1.Name = l2.Name and l1.Kind = l2.kind
where l1.occur_time > l2.occur_time
  and l1.value < l2.value
```

Basically this will find all mismatches, where the time grows, but the value diminishes.
It will return a lot of duplicates for every occurence, though, so you might have to restrict with something like this:

```
select distinct l1.Name, l1.Kind
from logs l1 -- self join on the columns that are the same
  inner join logs l2 on l1.Name = l2.Name and l1.Kind = l2.kind
where l1.occur_time > l2.occur_time
  and l1.value < l2.value
```

to isolate the problematic Name/Kind pairs

Comment: Hello I am currently running the query. Its taking time due to the large volume on the data on the db. I will return after. Please wait. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I got l1 l2. :) sorry for that question.

Comment: Executed for 00:01:30, returned 203823 results using select distinct. I will try to check the data and tell if its what I'm trying to look for. Thank you.

Comment: I see, its showing the tables side by side. How about if I just wanted to add another column AS comment. and put there beside the data if it is problematic or OKAY.

Comment: If the query works as intended, it should only produce problematic rows, with larger dates and smaller values on the left side that the right.

Comment: Hello, This works too. :) I wish I could make both answers check.

Comment: Hello, I have saved this too. But will use it on another occasion. Thank you very much.